# Why does fetch return the same results every time I run it?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Why does this fetch return the same results every time I run it.  And the results will only change if I manually go to https://tv-v2.api-fetch.website/random/movie and refresh the page?

```
fetch('https://tv-v2.api-fetch.website/random/movie')
   .then(res=>res.json())
   .then(r=>console.log(r))
```

Comment: Network caching more than likely

Comment: Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: `fetch('https://tv-v2.api-fetch.website/random/movie', {cache: "no-store"})` rtm: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache

Comment: that worked thanks!

Comment: @LawrenceCherone On the other hand, a `random` page shouldn't send any cache headers either, and yet it has `cache-control: max-age=604800`.

Comment: @Bergi yeah would need tweak settings on cloudflare

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @LawrenceCherone

```
fetch('https://tv-v2.api-fetch.website/random/movie', 

   {cache: "no-store"}) //no-store The cache should not store anything about the client request or server response.

   .then(res=>res.json())
   .then(r=>console.log(r))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control